# Ease of Detachment of a Space Helmet

Tags: spacesuits

How easy is it to disconnect and remove the helmet of a space suit? More specifically...

- How long does it take for one to remove his own helmet?
- Would it be feasible for somebody to remove another's helmet in a relatively quick manner?
- Would it be possible for somebody in vacuum to reattach his own helmet if it were removed?

I am aware that there are a variety of space suits, and I am under the impression that some EVA suits are more of a hard shell without a separately removable helmet. On that point, I welcome answers relating to any and every variety of suit you are familiar with.

Answer (score 4):

For the [Orlan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orlan_space_suit) spacesuits this is not possible. From [Encyclopedia Astronautica](http://www.astronautix.com/craft/orlan.htm)

> It consisted of flexible limbs attached to a one-piece rigid body / helmet unit.
>   The suit was entered through a hatch in the rear of the torso.

The helmets of the [Sokol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokol_space_suit) suits are easy to open, like shown in this video: (3:15)

The [Strizh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strizh_%28space_suit%29) suit seems to have the [same mechanism.](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b7/Strizh_spacesuit_4148047368_c19cec3782_o.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

For the Shuttle / ISS Extravehicular Mobility Unit, it is not too difficult:

> The connecting ring of the helmet is similar to the rings used for the
>   body-seal closure. Mobility is not needed in this ring because the
>   inside of the helmet is large enough  for  the  crew  member’s   head 
>   to  move around. To open or lock any of the connecting rings, one or
>   two sliding , rectangular-shaped knobs are moved to the right or the
>   left. When opened, the two halves of the connecting rings come apart
>   easily. To close and lock, one of the rings slides part way into the
>   other against an O-ring seal.The knob is moved to the right, and small
>   pins inside the outer ring protrude into a groove around the inside
>   ring, thereby holding the two together . All suit openings have
>   locking provisions that require a minimum of three independent motions
>   to open.This feature prevents any accidental opening of suit
>   connections.

From [here](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/188963main_Extravehicular_Mobility_Unit.pdf).